# Accessing static resource listbox by name

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, listbox

```
App.xaml
<Application.Resources>
. . . .
<StackPanel>
<ItemsPresenter/>
<ListBox x:Name="comm_box" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
. .. .
</Application.Resources>
```

error: comm_box doesn't exist in current context

How to resolve this problem?
I have listbox-news and listbox-comments that shows after listbox-news
But I can't set comm_box.Itemssource because comm_box is invisible.
Please help me.
http://pastebin.com/DERdgHJ9

Answer (score 1):

Try Application.Current.Resource["comm_box"]

Comment: There is no succes...Also I tried :`var comm_x = from i in this.Resources
                                     where i.Key.ToString() == "comm_box"
                                     select i;
                        ListBox comm_box = comm_x as ListBox;
                        comm_box.ItemsSource = comm_c;`

Comment: Do you get the same error? You should be able to do
`ListBox box = Application.Current.Resources["comm_box"] as ListBox;
box.ItemsSource = somethingsomething;
`
It's working fine for me.